# How to open Query Analyser (window) in Aqua Data

Tags: sql, database, ide, aquafold

To open Query Analyser (QA) in [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio.html) (ADS), I now right-click a table in de navigationpane en then select *Script Object To Window As* followed by *SELECT*

This is becoming cumbersome. Is there an easier why to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying to open Query Analyzer, make sure you are connected to a server first!

---

### To open QA in ADS, do one of the following:

- Use the computer keyboard command: `Ctrl+Q` 
  (or `Ctrl+Shift+W` to open QA in a separate window).
- Click *Server* on the *Toolbar* and select *Query Analyzer*.
- In the navigation-bar, Right-click any node that is showing under your connected server and select *Query Analyzer*.

Comment: When I double click files in the Filesystem tree they open in an 'Editor' window.  Is it possible to get them to open into a new 'Query Analyser' window instead?